# How to display different custom images on endpoints of cluster in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

Like the image below I want to display different custom images on the endpoints of cluster in Mapbox. Is there someone who can help because it is really confusing and I don't know if it even is possible?

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYHNg.png)

I've looked everywhere but can't find an example of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

this seem to explain how to do it with Mapbox:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/

Additionally not sure if you're married to Mapbox, but Google seem to have a more robust offering on the customization side of Markers:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#simple_icons

Comment: We have our own theme on Mapbox theme so we would like to keep mapbox. Thank's for sharing the example but they're not using clusters there and are just grabbing an image from a random image API so it's not fully custom from the location data. Any further ideas that can help maybe?